# How to do sum with where clause group by with date?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, pivot

I want to sum up where clause. I don't know how to show off_duration in the next column.

```
SELECT CAST([RecordDateTime] AS DATE) AS DATE
    ,SUM(CAST([units] AS FLOAT)) AS Units
    ,sum(cast(duration AS INT) / 60) on_duration
FROM [Energies]
WHERE duration_mode = 'ON'
GROUP BY CAST([RecordDateTime] AS DATE)
ORDER BY CAST([RecordDateTime] AS DATE) DESC
```

op

```
 Datet      units   on_duration
-------------------------------
2020-01-17  3.53    758
2020-01-16  7.66    973
2020-01-15  15.12   1806
2020-01-13  10.4    500
```

ex op

```
date        units   on_duration    off_duration
-----------------------------------------------
2020-01-17  3.53    758            28
2020-01-16  7.66    973             9
2020-01-15  15.12   1806           96
2020-01-13  10.4    500            95
```

sample data

```
duration_mode   duration    RecordDateTime             units 
-------------------------------------------------------------
ON              187     2020-01-07 20:18:33.9744232     0.19
ON              187     2020-01-07 20:19:03.1554359     0.19
OFF             10      2020-01-07 20:22:13.5283932     0.00
ON              187     2020-01-07 20:24:39.0510166     0.19
```

Comment: I don't understand your logic here. Explain your results. What does `off_duration` represent, and how is it calculated (from your sample data). I *thought* it might be to do with rows where the value of `duration_mode` is `'OFF'`, however, you filter those out in the `WHERE`; so it can't be that.

Comment: `sum(case when duration_mode = 'OFF' then duration end)` Remove the filter to get both rows in the group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are looking for conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT 
    CAST([RecordDateTime] AS DATE) as Date, 
    SUM(CAST([units] as float)) as Units, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN duration_mode = 'ON' THEN CAST(duration as int)/60 END) on_duration,
    SUM(CASE WHEN duration_mode = 'OFF' THEN CAST(duration as int)/60 END) off_duration
FROM [Energies]
GROUP BY CAST([RecordDateTime] AS DATE)
ORDER BY CAST([RecordDateTime] AS DATE) desc
```

Comment: can u please tell me , how to do trim upto 2 decimal,7.87999999999999 exp op - 7.87 in the units.it should be another question but for time being.

Comment: @krishnamohan: use `round(..., 2)`.